# SAXParseException Using Maven-JAXB2 0.7.5 Plugin, Only On Maven 3

Tags: spring-ws, jaxb2, maven-jaxb2-plugin

I seem to be having issues with the maven-jaxb2-plugin (Version 0.7.5) when using Maven 3. *The issue doesn't occur when using Maven 2.2.x, and it only became an issue when I upgraded to Maven 3*.

Following is the maven output after executing mvn clean test:

> ```
> [ERROR] Error while parsing schema(s).Location 
>     [ file:/C:/dev/smart-07-2011/mpg-money-send-service/src/main/resources/META-INF/mpg/schemas/XRSIMoneySend.xsd{218,45}].
>  org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: src-resolve: 
>      Cannot resolve the name 'common:ResponseBody' to 
>      a(n) 'type definition' component.
> ```

However, the tests execute fine when using Maven 2. I've been searching for resources online if there's any known issue between Maven 3 and JAXB2, but I couldn't find any resources. Effective POM for the build using Maven 2 or Maven 3 is identical.

Incidentally, in the past I was able to use the maven-jaxb2-plugin on Maven 3 just fine; this build, however is special in that the XSD is in a dependent JAR, so it could be a configuration issue; but I'm not sure what configuration I would need to set in the POM or bindings.

Are there any resources I could use to resolve this issue, or any resolution steps I could take? Thanks a lot!